# FullCalendar.IO not displayng at first sight

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

Well, some time ago i have uploaded my website and everything was working fine till this week.

What is happening?

When page loads, FullCalendar simply not display events, on console, i cannot see any erros, everything seems ok, but Fullcalendar is not displaying.
BUT

When i go down do Create page, and i create a new event, and turn back to index, i can see all the events that i've already created.
I really cant understand what is running wrong.

so, the problem is: when you visit the website for the first time, simply not display events.
but when you create a new event and go back, evetyhing works fine.

here is my code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert("CARREGOU");
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        eventSources: [
            '../../Fixare/Calendario/GetListaEventos'
        ],
        locale: 'pt-br',
        titleFormat: 'MMMM',
        editable: false,
        cache: true,
        allDayDefault: true,
        eventLimit: false

    });
});
```

Comment: Well I don't know what's involved in your create events process, or why that works. It's not shown here and there's no context for it. So I don't know if that's actually relevant or just coincidence.

Comment: But...the obvious thing to do is: the first time you visit the site, watch the "Network" tab in your browser. Look for the request to the GetListaEventos URL. Watch for the response. Do you get the expected response? What is inside the response, exactly? Show us the JSON which is returned by the server. Maybe it returns no events, or maybe the response is incorrect in some way.

Comment: @ADyson THANK YOU!

I've found the problem:
My controller was with [AUTHORIZE] tag, on MVC.
So, when i try to get the events, i need to be authorized, when i go to the 'create' i have to put my user and password, so after that, i'm able to get events.
Solution:
Put an [AllowAnonymous] tag on the GetListaEventos method.

Thank you all.

Comment: No problem. Just check it's not a security problem for you though, because someone outside your application (e.g. using some other tool like PostMan or cURL) could make a request to that anonymous method and get the data. It might be better to organise it so that the correct credentials are passed to the server during the ajax request. You can set extra ajax options in the eventSource object, to help with that if necessary. Obviously I don't know your specific situation so can't give more detailed advice, but IMO that would be a more correct and more secure solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem:
My controller was with [AUTHORIZE] tag, on MVC.
So, when i try to get the events, i need to be authorized, when i go to the 'create' i have to put my user and password, so after that, i'm able to get events.
Solution:
Put an [AllowAnonymous] tag on the GetListaEventos method.

Thank you all.